# How to declare an array with different object types in rust

Tags: rust, vector, struct, actix-web

I have a callback to my API that returns an object with one of its items as a vector with different types. In rust a vector can only be declared with one type of elements. How can i go about this issues?

```
{    
   "Body": {        
      "xxx": {            
         "xxx": "29115-34620561-1",            
         "xxx": "ws_CO_191220191020363925",            
         "xxx": 0,            
         "xxx": "The service request is processed successfully.",            
         "CallbackMetadata": {                
            "Item": [{                        
               "Name": "Amount",                        
               "Value": 1.00                    
            },                    
            {                        
               "Name": "ReceiptNumber",                        
               "Value": "NLJ7RT61SV"                    
            },                    
            {                        
               "Name": "Date",                        
               "Value": 20191219102115                    
            },                    
            {                        
               "Name": "number",                        
               "Value": 74149                    
            }]            
         }        
      }    
   }
}
```

> in the body object the callback object has **Item** which is a vector of different types. How can I declare the vector type to have different types as element in the **CallbackMetadata.Items** struct?

I tried declaring each Item to have an Any type on the value but could not beat the compiler.

```
pub struct Item {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: dyn Any,
}
```

Comment: While using an enum is generally the right way to go, you can also make this work with `value: Box<dyn Any>` and Any::downcast. I generally recommend *against* using Any.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum:

```
enum MyType {
   Float(f32),
   Integer(i32),
   Text(String),
}
```

Then your struct looks like this:

```
pub struct Item {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: MyType,
}
```

Comment: The `Integer` variant probably needs to hold an `i64` as one of the examples in the data is out of range for `i32`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're actually dealing with JSON, I highly recommend using the `serde-json` library, which has a [`Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html) enum that represents all valid JSON values:

```rust
use serde_json::Value;

const TEXT: &str = r#"
{    
   "Body": {        
      "xxx": {            
         "xxx": "29115-34620561-1",            
         "xxx": "ws_CO_191220191020363925",            
         "xxx": 0,            
         "xxx": "The service request is processed successfully.",            
         "CallbackMetadata": {                
            "Item": [{                        
               "Name": "Amount",                        
               "Value": 1.00                    
            },                    
            {                        
               "Name": "ReceiptNumber",                        
               "Value": "NLJ7RT61SV"                    
            },                    
            {                        
               "Name": "Date",                        
               "Value": 20191219102115                    
            },                    
            {                        
               "Name": "number",                        
               "Value": 74149                    
            }]            
         }        
      }    
   }
}
"#;

fn main() {
    let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(TEXT).expect("valid json");
    let items = json["Body"]["xxx"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"]
        .as_array()
        .expect("Item to be an array");
    for item in items {
        println!("Item: {item:?}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enums as mentioned in the other answeres, but If you don’t know the exhaustive set of types a program will get at runtime to store in a vector, the enum technique won’t work.
In that case we can use something like the following:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn my_method(&self);
}

struct TypeA;
struct TypeB;

impl MyTrait for TypeA {
    fn my_method(&self) {
        println!("TypeA method called");
    }
}

impl MyTrait for TypeB {
    fn my_method(&self) {
        println!("TypeB method called");
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Create a vector of trait objects
    let mut my_vector: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = Vec::new();

    // Push instances of types implementing MyTrait to the vector
    my_vector.push(Box::new(TypeA{}));
    my_vector.push(Box::new(TypeB{}));
}
```